# Shopware 6 CI and Post Deploy

Tags: deployment, shopware

I am trying to set up continuous integration for a Shopware 6 store via Github Actions. Once the code is on the server, I am running the following commands in order to complete the deploy. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a good tutorial or article on the post deploy steps necessary.

- Which folders need write permissions?
- Which console commands need to fire? Which ones are optional? (cache:clear theme:compile and so on?
- Which npm commands are mandatory?
- what's the config/jwt folder with its certificates and what certificates go in there?
- Are there additional commands needed to get DB Migrations running?

```
sudo php bin/console cache:clear
sudo php bin/console dal:refresh:index
sudo php bin/console theme:compile

sudo rm -rf var/cache
sudo /usr/bin/npm clean-install --prefix vendor/shopware/administration/Resources
sudo /usr/bin/npm run --prefix vendor/shopware/administration/Resources lerna -- bootstrap
sudo /usr/bin/npm clean-install --prefix vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront /
sudo /usr/bin/node vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/copy-to-vendor.js
sudo php bin/console bundle:dump
sudo sh bin/build-js.sh
PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/path-to-shopware/ sudo /usr/bin/npm --prefix vendor/shopware/storefront/Resources/app/storefront/ run production
```

It would be great to learn how others deploy SW6 and to compare this to what others need to do, once the Shopware 6 code is on the server. What tools do you use? Ansible or any other tools. Although this mostly works, I cannot use updates due to an error coming from the API.

Comment: Did you make progress? Also interested in that...

Comment: Since everybody in the slack channel has recommended to use either ansible or ansistrano, I switched to ansible and currently trigger deploys manually. There is an ansible github action though, which can be used to auto trigger the deploy and it just needs the vault pass. I am avoiding and not running the npm build stuff all the time.